# Makefile error - *** No rule to make target , C

Tags: c, makefile

I am learning C and I am trying to call a rule that I have had to write in a makefile:

```
CFlAGS=-Wall -g

clean:
    rm -f ex1
```

However when I enter the command `$make clean` I get the error:

`make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.`
I am using Cygwin64 terminal on windows and I have stored the makefile under the name ex2.mak however it is still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make` looks for the makefile with the name `Makefile`.

You can use the `-f` option to tell it to look somewhere else, like so:

```
make -f ex2.mak clean
```

or you can rename the makefile to `Makefile`.

Comment: Also it's better to mark `clean` as a `PHONY` target.

Answer (score 0):

Most beginners' problems with makefiles is: The command (in your case the line containing "rm..." does not begin with a *real tab character*. If it doesn't, the makefile will not be correctly interpreted.

If you write a makefile, make sure your editor does not convert tabs to spaces and also make sure that *you* don't type spaces instead of tab characters. Other than that, the makefile looks O.K. to me so far.